# C++ Wininet FtpOpenFile succeeds to open .txt but how do I save it as string?

Tags: c++

I'm a big noob at C++ but I'm trying to learn!
I managed to connect and open a .txt file on my FTP server like this:

```
    bool openFile = FtpOpenFile(hFtpSession, "text.txt", GENERIC_READ, INTERNET_FLAG_TRANSFER_ASCII, 0);
    if (openFile == TRUE)
    {
        cout << "Opened file!" << endl;
    }
```

And it works without problem, but the question is how do I save whats inside of the .txt file into a string?

Answer (score 1):

`FtpOpenFile` doesn't return a `bool`. Here's the prototype from the MSDN docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384166(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
HINTERNET FtpOpenFile(
  _In_ HINTERNET hConnect,
  _In_ LPCTSTR   lpszFileName,
  _In_ DWORD     dwAccess,
  _In_ DWORD     dwFlags,
  _In_ DWORD_PTR dwContext
);
```

Use the handle that's returned to read the file using `InternetReadFile` function.

Comment: You need to use `InternetReadFile()` instead of `ReadFile()`. And don't forget to call `InternetCloseHandle()` to close the `HINTERNET` handle when the transfer is finished.

Comment: I used the bool to see if it suceeded to open the file on my FTP server which it did. But the problem is that I have no idea on how to save the .txt in a string. But I will look into InternetReadFile()

Comment: But it doesn't return a bool. The correct way to see if it succeeded is to check if the return value is not NULL.